# Exporting piece of data from the SQL Server by percentage

Tags: sql-server

Suppose that the database size is too big. How can I export only 30 percent of that database for my development purposes?
I need the full schema and only 30% of the data!

Comment: is the data spread evenly across the schema, or do you have some tables taking up much more space than others? there's no generic solution to this.

Comment: A blanket 30% may break your DB if you have Foreign Keys

Comment: three tables are much bigger than the others. we have some tables with no relationship defined and a few tables with FK relationship.